# How to make time slots without the need for real time (it is just simulation)

Tags: c++, timeslots

now i am making a simulation for something and i need to define time slots for it as i can not use the real time . For example , i want to know how many persons entered the bank in the 1st 5 minutes and then in the second 5 mins and so on , i want to simulate only so i do not wait 5 miin every time to be able to take the results.

can anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

You keep a priority queue of future events sorted by arrival time.  Then just take the first and handle it until there is no more event remaining.

Comment: Thanks alot for reply in advance :-)
but all what i want to is to calcualte for example the number of persons came in the first slot. in the code i don not know when these persons arrive . 

also i want to insert to it a  definition for the timeslot to be able to calculate the delay for one person.

do you understand what i am trying to do or you need more explanation :-) ??

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but it sounds like [Discrete Event Simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation) could help.

Comment: i think it can help :-) or actually it helps , thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @fank If it was the solution for your problem, mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need two things.

1. To maintain a record of how many arrivals occurred by timeslot.  This is called a histogram.  The timeslot ( usually called a bin when discussing histograms in general ) of each arrival is calculated ( integer division is often useful here ) and the correct bin count ( array or vector ) is incremented.
2. To estimate the delay experienced by each arrival.  This requires discrete event simulation - a big subject. The Wikipedia article is probably a good start.

Comment: thanks for reply 

i worked before with the discrete time event simulation but sorry i can not understand well how i can implement the 1st thing 
concerning the histograms. 
can you explain more or give me a website or anything to understand more?? :-)


the question is : can i use these histograms and timeslots without using real time? 
thanks alot

Comment: Histograms: Construction, Analysis and Understanding http://quarknet.fnal.gov/toolkits/ati/histograms.html